# How to handle additional files when building and running a AUR package?

Tags: bash, shell, pkgbuild, pacman-package-manager

So I was just playing around and created this simple Shell script:

**TestScript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "read or write? " INP

if [[ "${INP}" == "write" ]] 
then
    read -p "Write your text: " TEXT
    touch /usr/share/textfile.txt
    echo "${TEXT}" >> /usr/share/textfile.txt
else
    cat /usr/share/textfile.txt
fi
```

which of course can easily read and write into a file under /usr after gaining sudo priviliges:

> sudo sh TestScript.sh

Based on this file I create a test PKGBUILD to install TestScript.sh via pacman later on:

**PKGBUILD**

```
# Maintainer: Your Name <youremail@domain.com>
pkgname='test-script'
pkgver=1
pkgrel=1
pkgdesc="AUR test package"
arch=('x86_64')
license=('custom')
source=('TestScript.sh')
md5sums=('SKIP')

package() {
    mkdir -p "${pkgdir}/usr/bin"
    cp "${srcdir}/TestScript.sh" "${pkgdir}/usr/bin/TestScript"
    chmod +x "${pkgdir}/usr/bin/TestScript"
}
```

Followed by

> makepkg

> sudo pacman -U test-script-1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

I can run

> TestScript

from the command line. But just as I thought, I am unable to write into /usr/share/textfile.txt .
I was searching the [Arch-Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PKGBUILD) up and down, but I couldn't find out how to handle this situation. I basically just want to have a location where I can properly read and write a file without messing up the user space.
Does anyone have an idea?